# Resize canvas elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, charts

I am looking for an easy solution to resize a canvas element (a chart) automatically once the parent div size changes (= browser size changes). At the moment my Canvas element only fits perfectly into the parent div when the page is loaded.

This is what I've done so far and what I've tried:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <canvas id="userlogins"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            var ctx = $("#userlogins").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
        });


        function fitToContainer(canvas){
          // Make it visually fill the positioned parent
          canvas.style.width ='100%';
          // ...then set the internal size to match
          canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
        }

        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        fitToContainer(canvas);

        jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
            fitToContainer(canvas);
            redraw();
        });

    </script>
</div>
```

When I resize my browser the canvas chart disappears. The parent div fit on page load works well.

Edit: The approaches in the given "duplicates" doesn't work for me! Here is what I have tried given from the "duplicate question":

```
jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerID = setTimeout(function() {
        var cnvs = $("#userlogins")[0];                  // cache canvas element
        var rect = cnvs.getBoundingClientRect();   // actual size of canvas el. itself

        cnvs.width = rect.width;
        cnvs.height = rect.height;
        redraw();
    });
});
```

Comment: Search well before questioning please.

Comment: the given approaches in the "duplicated" question doesn't work for me thus I have created this question...

Comment: There it says `parentNode` while your edit doesn't spell parent. Probably you are resizing to whatever size it already has.

Comment: Vesper can you explain this to me in more detail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using ChartJS. If yes, it has a property you can set to make the chart responsive to resizing.

```
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for such an easy solution. Yes it was ChartJS.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the canvas element width or height clears the canvas. In fact, it's often used as a way of clearing it on purpose. So this line:

```
canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
```

clears your canvas. After that, you can either:

- redraw the chart
- or remove that line and rely on the CSS transformations, which can ruin the proportions of your canvas